# How can I get my api return object with useMutation?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I use C# api and my api return an uid after the creation of the element.
But when I use useMutation I don't get my uid in the response object.
How can I get it ?

```
function creationTrunk(note) {
    const { isLoading, isSuccess, isError, data, error, mutate } = ReactQuery.useMutation(['createNote'], async () => await fetch(`api/createNote?note=${note}`, {
        method: 'POST'
    }), {
            onSuccess: (res) => {
            console.log(res)
            return res.json()
        },
            onError: (err) => {
            return res.json()
        }
    })

    return { isLoading, isSuccess, isError, data, error, mutate }
}
```

this is what in get with my `console.log(res)`

[image: console.log]

Answer (score 0):

```
    function useCreationTrunk() {    
    
        return useMutation((note) => fetch(`api/createNote`, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: note
            }).then(res => res.json()), {
                    onSuccess: (resData) => {
                    console.log(resData)
                    }
            });
    }
```

Then you can use this hook in your component.

```
const { isLoading, isSuccess, isError, data, error, mutate } = useCreationTrunk();
const note = {...}
useCreationTrunkMutation.mutate(note);
console.log(data);
```